# Should "System" chunks be included in a btrfs RAID1 balance?

Tags: raid1, btrfs

The [`btrfs` wiki RAID1 conversion example](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Using_Btrfs_with_Multiple_Devices#Conversion) gives the following command:

> ```
> btrfs balance start -dconvert=raid1 -mconvert=raid1 /mnt
> ```

There is also the option `-s` which `man btrfs-balance page defines as:

> act on system chunks (requires -f)

So, why not also do `-sconvert=raid1` when converting RAID0 to RAID1?

Answer (score 0):

Don't pass `-f -s`, [this `btrfs` mailing list post](https://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-btrfs/msg33573.html) says it's dangerous.

It is not necessary to pass `-s`: `System` chunks are converted to `RAID1` automatically:

Before `balance`:

```
[tara /]# btrfs fil df /ark 
Data, single: total=2.16TiB, used=2.16TiB
System, DUP: total=8.00MiB, used=256.00KiB
Metadata, DUP: total=7.50GiB, used=5.41GiB
GlobalReserve, single: total=512.00MiB, used=0.00B
```

After `btrfs bal start -dconvert=raid1 -mconvert=raid1 /ark`:

```
[tara /]# btrfs fil df /ark 
Data, RAID1: total=2.16TiB, used=2.16TiB
System, RAID1: total=32.00MiB, used=336.00KiB
Metadata, RAID1: total=14.00GiB, used=5.62GiB
GlobalReserve, single: total=512.00MiB, used=0.00B
```

Note:

- `Sytstem, DUP` changed to `RAID1` above.
- [GlobalReserve is always `single`](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/FAQ#What_is_the_GlobalReserve_and_why_does_.27btrfs_fi_df.27_show_it_as_single_even_on_RAID_filesystems.3F) (and not stored on disk).

Comment: Why is `GlobalReserve` still single? That would make me worry, especially if its `used` becomes non-zero eventally...

Comment: @not-a-user Good question. I've updated my answer, please see above.

Comment: Can confirm this, on Linux 5.5.11: Converted metadata only (`-mconvert=raid1`), left data as raid0 in my case, and System was converted automatically to raid1.

Comment: Converting system blocks to RAID1 are dangerous but this is done implicitly? Does this make sense?

Comment: `-mconvert=raid1,soft` suffices to fix `System,DUP`, see also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/336909/btrfs-balance-completed-but-still-shows-data-stored-in-single-mode